# Preventing WPF form submit on pressing Enter key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF XAML screen having multiple controls (textboxes, comboboxes, buttons, etc.). The code behind is in C#. I've kept `IsDefault="True"` for one of the buttons. Due to this, if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in any of the textboxes, the form gets submitted.

I need to submit the form using <kbd>Enter</kbd> key only for one specific textbox. If the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in any of the other textboxes, I don't want the form to be submitted.

I know I can achieve this using code behind (i.e. `*.xaml.cs`). But how can I achieve this using the MVVM design pattern?

Comment: Create attached behavior that will wire up the appropriate key event to handle the enter key.

Comment: Well, this is the work for code-behind, since this is view logic.

Answer (score 2):

You likely don't care what text box the user presses enter in, you just want the entire form to be completed. If this is the case perform validation and disable the button using your binding.

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveCommand == null)
            _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Save(), CanSave);

        return _saveCommand;
    }
}

private void CanSave(object sender)
{
    // Validate properties, ensure viewmodel is in savable state.

    // Maybe you implemented IDataErrorInfo?
    if (Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this, null, null), new List<ValidationResult>(), true))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void Save()
{
    // Database stuff, maybe WCF stuff, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks FrumRoll for your comments.But as I mentioned,I need to submit the form only if user has pressed enter in one specific textbox(lets say txtboxProductKey).Form submit should not get triggered for any other textbox whether or not user has entered value in txtboxProductKey.

Comment: @Vineetv you can of course validate all of your bound values, not only the ProductKey. But if you only want to use the single text box to fire the command, I would remove IsDefault="True" from your button, and simply bind the command to the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the IsDefault property of the Button to the IsFocused property of the allowed TextBox, like below.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="TB1" Grid.Row="0" Height="15" Width="300">

    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TB2" Grid.Row="1" Height="15" Width="300">

    </TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="200" Content="Button"
            IsDefault="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=TB2}"  Click="Button_Click">
    </Button>
```

I had had it so the IsEnabled property was bound, but it prevented button clicks from working.  I then tried multi-binding it based on the focus of TB2 or the Button, but that still prevented clicks if TB1 was focused because the disabled button couldn't accept clicks to take focus.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `AcceptsReturn="True"` on the textboxes that you want to handle enter themselves rather than routing to the form.

Comment: That works but turns the textboxes into multiline textboxes. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Not as far as I can see on Windows 8/10 where the MaxLines property does not work correctly.  I think you may have to resort to a derived control with a keyboard event handler that swallows the keypress.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove IsDefault="True" from your button and bind your command to the textbox itself. There are a number of ways to do this on StackOverflow. My preference is to use a custom textbox.

```
public class CommandTextBox : TextBox, ICommandSource
{
    private bool _canExecute;
    private EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;

    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Command != null)
                return base.IsEnabledCore && _canExecute;

            return base.IsEnabledCore;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(OnCommandChanged));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandTextBox));

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandTarget", typeof(IInputElement), typeof(CommandTextBox));

    public IInputElement CommandTarget
    {
        get { return (IInputElement)GetValue(CommandTargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandTargetProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (Command != null)
            {
                RoutedCommand command = Command as RoutedCommand;

                if (command != null)
                    command.Execute(CommandParameter, CommandTarget);
                else
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void AddCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        var handler = new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged);
        _canExecuteChanged = handler;
        if (command != null)
            command.CanExecuteChanged += _canExecuteChanged;
    }

    private void CanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command != null)
        {
            RoutedCommand command = Command as RoutedCommand;

            // If a RoutedCommand. 
            if (command != null)
                _canExecute = command.CanExecute(CommandParameter, CommandTarget);
            else
                _canExecute = Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter);
        }

        CoerceValue(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    private void HookUpCommand(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
    {
        // If oldCommand is not null, then we need to remove the handlers. 
        if (oldCommand != null)
            RemoveCommand(oldCommand);

        AddCommand(newCommand);
    }

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CommandTextBox)d).HookUpCommand((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void RemoveCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        command.CanExecuteChanged -= handler;
    }
}
```